# I want to optimize this query, it takes lots of time to execute

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, select, query-optimization

si want to optimize this query which takes lots of time to execute.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  j1.job_id,
  j1.job_name,
  j1.client_id,
  j1.job_status_id,
  j1.int_job_status_id,
  j1.job_type_id,
  j1.job_due_date,
  j1.job_received,
  c1.client_name,
  c1.id,
  j1.period,
  j1.notes,
  j1.staff_notes,
  j1.job_genre,
  j1.job_submitted,
  j1.mas_Code,
  DATE_FORMAT(j1.job_completed_date, '%d/%m/%Y')    completedDate,
  j1.invoiceno,
  j1.is_active,
  p1.name,
  s1.job_status
FROM CLIENT c1,
  pr_practice p1,
  sub_subactivity sa,
  job_status s1,
  job j1
  LEFT JOIN task t
    ON j1.job_id = t.job_id
  LEFT JOIN task_assign ta
    ON ta.task_id = t.task_id
WHERE j1.client_id = c1.client_id
    AND c1.id = p1.id
    AND t.job_id = j1.job_id
    AND sa.sub_Code = j1.job_type_id
    AND j1.job_status_id = s1.job_status_id
    AND j1.discontinue_date IS NULL
    AND j1.job_submitted = 'Y'
    AND j1.job_status_id <> 7
    AND p1.id = c1.id
    AND (j1.job_type_id IN(8,5,6,9,19,19,7,16,17)
         AND (FIND_IN_SET(134,p1.sr_manager)
               OR FIND_IN_SET(134,p1.manager)
               OR FIND_IN_SET(134,p1.tl1)
               OR FIND_IN_SET(134,p1.tl2)
               OR FIND_IN_SET(134,p1.tl3)
               OR FIND_IN_SET(134,p1.tl4)
               OR FIND_IN_SET(134,p1.sales))
          OR ta.assignee_id IN(134))
    AND j1.is_active = 1
ORDER BY j1.job_received DESC, j1.job_id DESC
LIMIT 0,25
```

Client Table

```
client_id int(11)  | id int(11) (practice Id)
```

Practice Table

```
id int(11) | sr_manager | manager | t1 |t2 |t3 |t4 |sales varchar(255)
```

Job table

```
j1.job_id,   j1.job_name,   j1.client_id,   j1.job_status_id,   j1.int_job_status_id,  j1.job_type_id,   j1.job_due_date,   j1.job_received,  j1.period,
  j1.notes,  j1.staff_notes,  j1.job_genre,  j1.job_submitted,  j1.mas_Code etc.
```

Task table

```
task_id | id (practice id) | client_id | job_id
```

Task Assignee

```
id | task_id | assignee_id
```

Please advice !

Comment: Use `explain` to find out what indexes to use.

Comment: Or remove tables from your query one at a time until you find the slow join. Then add an appropriate index to speed it up.

Comment: `FIND_IN_SET(134,p1.sr_manager)` <--- you store data in a terrible way == you get terrible performance (not only that, but that too)

Comment: why are you combining old pre ansi joins with ansi joins? what? just join all tables

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT j1.job_id, j1.job_name, j1.client_id, j1.job_status_id, 
         j1.int_job_status_id, j1.job_type_id, j1.job_due_date, j1.job_received, 
         c1.client_name, c1.id, j1.period, j1.notes, j1.staff_notes, j1.job_genre, 
         j1.job_submitted, j1.mas_Code, DATE_FORMAT(j1.job_completed_date, '%d/%m/%Y') completedDate, 
         j1.invoiceno, j1.is_active, p1.name, s1.job_status
FROM CLIENT c1, 
INNER JOIN pr_practice p1 ON c1.id = p1.id 
INNER JOIN job j1 ON j1.client_id = c1.client_id AND j1.is_active = 1
INNER JOIN sub_subactivity sa ON sa.sub_Code = j1.job_type_id
INNER JOIN job_status s1 ON j1.job_status_id = s1.job_status_id
LEFT JOIN task t ON j1.job_id = t.job_id
LEFT JOIN task_assign ta ON ta.task_id = t.task_id
WHERE j1.discontinue_date IS NULL AND j1.job_submitted = 'Y' AND 
        j1.job_status_id <> 7 AND j1.job_type_id IN (8,5,6,9,19,19,7,16,17) AND 
       FIND_IN_SET(134, CONCAT_WS(',', p1.sr_manager, p1.manager, p1.tl1, p1.tl2, p1.tl3, p1.tl4, p1.sales, ta.assignee_id))    
ORDER BY j1.job_received DESC, j1.job_id DESC
LIMIT 0,25
```

Comment: NOTE: this query is a slightly different specification than the original. Given the order of precedence of `AND`/`OR` boolean operators, in the original statement, with the `OR` condition on the `ta.assignee_id` predicate, the condition on `j1.job_type_id` isn't applied. Also in the original, the `t.job_id = j1.job_id` predicate in the `WHERE` clause effectively negates the "outerness" of the `LEFT JOIN task t` operation.

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't identify any indexes on any of the tables.

A key to SQL performance is understanding what operations available to the optimizer, and how MySQL determines which operations to choose from those available. Having suitable indexes available can give MySQL the ability to make use of those for a more efficient execution plan.

Absent the output from `EXPLAIN`, we are left to guess at the execution plan.

Our initial knee-jerk reaction to slow performance is to add appropriate indexes. Or second thought is that MySQL doesn't always make the most efficient choices when the predicates include `OR` conditions. The LIMIT clause is applied last in the processing... MySQL is going to process the DISTINCT and ORDER BY operations on the entire resultset, before the LIMIT is applied. And a `Using filesort` operation can be expensive on large sets.

As a first cut at defining indexes which might be appropriate:

```
... ON job (discontinue_date, is_active, job_submitted, job_received, job_id, job_status_id)
... ON job_status (job_status_id, job_status)
... ON pr_practice (id)
... ON sub_subactivity (sub_Code)
... ON task (job_id, task_id)
... ON task_assign (task_id, assignee_id)
... ON CLIENT (client_id, id, client_name)
```

We would really need to see the output from `EXPLAIN` to understand whether MySQL is making use of any of those indexes, and we'd need to test performance.

---

We typically avoid using the old-school comma syntax for a join operation; we prefer to use the newer `JOIN` keyword syntax, and relocate the join predicates from the `WHERE` clause to an appropriate ON clause. . (The comma syntax is still available and supported, but that's mostly useful for compatibility with older SQL.)

---

We could re-write the query, preserving the same specification as the original SQL, though this will not likely change the execution plan, and therefore won't result in any difference in performance:

```
SELECT DISTINCT j1.job_id
     , j1.job_name
     , j1.client_id
     , j1.job_status_id
     , j1.int_job_status_id
     , j1.job_type_id
     , j1.job_due_date
     , j1.job_received
     , c1.client_name
     , c1.id
     , j1.period
     , j1.notes
     , j1.staff_notes
     , j1.job_genre
     , j1.job_submitted
     , j1.mas_Code
     , DATE_FORMAT(j1.job_completed_date, '%d/%m/%Y') AS completedDate
     , j1.invoiceno
     , j1.is_active
     , p1.name
     , s1.job_status
  FROM job              j1
  JOIN CLIENT           c1 ON c1.client_id     = j1.client_id
  JOIN pr_practice      p1 ON p1.id            = c1.id
  JOIN job_status       s1 ON s1.job_status_id = j1.job_status_id
  JOIN sub_subactivity  sa ON sa.sub_Code      = j1.job_type_id
  JOIN task             t  ON t.job_id         = j1.job_id
  LEFT JOIN task_assign ta ON ta.task_id       = t.task_id
 WHERE j1.discontinue_date IS NULL
   AND j1.job_submitted = 'Y'
   AND j1.job_status_id <> 7
   AND j1.is_active = 1
   AND ( ( j1.job_type_id IN (8,5,6,9,19,19,7,16,17)
         AND (  FIND_IN_SET(134,p1.sr_manager)
             OR FIND_IN_SET(134,p1.manager)
             OR FIND_IN_SET(134,p1.tl1)
             OR FIND_IN_SET(134,p1.tl2)
             OR FIND_IN_SET(134,p1.tl3)
             OR FIND_IN_SET(134,p1.tl4)
             OR FIND_IN_SET(134,p1.sales)
             )
         )
       OR ta.assignee_id IN (134)
       )
 ORDER BY j1.job_received DESC, j1.job_id DESC
 LIMIT 0,25
```

Note that the `OR ta.assignee_id` predicate ignores the predicate on j1.job_type_id, due to the precedence of the AND and OR boolean operators. The addition of the parens in the re-written query preserve this behavior. Also, the `t.job_id = j1.job_id` predicate in the `WHERE` clause of the original query effectively negates the "outerness" of the `LEFT JOIN task t` operation, rendering it equivalent to an `INNER JOIN`.